# Laravel-Mix: Vue not available in app.js and bootstrap.js after Laravel-Mix upgrade to v6

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

So I just upgraded from Laravel-Mix v1 to v6.

For example, in `app.js` I do the following to register all Vue components:

```
const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key)))
```

But I get this error:

`app.js:17638 Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined`

I read about it and added these lines in webpack.mix.js:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }
}
```

but unfortunately that doesn't do anything. Same error still.

When I add `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'` on top of app.js and bootstrap.js I don't get these error no longer, but the code for registering vue components is not working.

Bootstrap.js: https://www.codepile.net/pile/8rX4Qlrm
package.json: https://www.codepile.net/pile/JBA4NYLk

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: please share your `app.js` and `package.json` files

Comment: Bootstrap.js: https://www.codepile.net/pile/8rX4Qlrm
package.json: https://www.codepile.net/pile/JBA4NYLk

Comment: add the line `window.Vue = require('vue');` just below `import Vue from 'vue';` in app.js

Comment: I already have `window.Vue = require('vue');` in app.js. The important is not needed afaik. When I add the import it says it doesn't know `Vue.component`

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I have the same issue

Comment: updated for you

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
window.Vue = require("Vue");
```

to

```
import Vue from "Vue";
```